# How to make a gameObject invisible?

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

I am attempting to make a Unity gameObject invisible through code. So far I have tried (On a script attached to the gameObject I want to make invisible): `this.renderer.enabled = false`
`this.enabled = false`
`this.gameObject.enabled = false`
`this.gameObject.renderer.enabled = false`
And on my player script: `other.gameObject.enabled = false`
`other.gameObject.renderer.enabled = false`
I have also tried `Destroy (other.gameObject)` but it doesn't achieve what I want from it.

Thanks for your help

Edit:
Here is my code using the `gameObject.SetActive` command

```
    void Update () 
{
    if (BlueFlag.GotBlueFlag == false) 
    {
        print ("false");
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    if (BlueFlag.GotBlueFlag == true) 
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(true);
        print ("True");
    }
}
```

It works now, in part. However, it seems that it won't register if the GotBlueFlag bool on the BlueFlag script is true. If I use double "=" signs, It spams my "True" print statement. Ideas?

Another Edit: (Showing the BlueFlag script)

```
    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
{
    if (other.collider.tag == "RedTank") 
    {
        print ("Flag");
        gameObject.SetActive (false);
        GotBlueFlag = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use below code:

```
gameObject.SetActive(false);
```

Documents [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html). Note that enabled is obsolete in the new Unity API!

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly. I was afraid I wasn't going to have this done tonight.

Comment: Note that while this may well be what you're after, it does rather more than simply making the object "invisible". Strictly speaking, I think the only way to do that would be to set all its alphas to zero.

Comment: More than? What else? Can you give more details?

Comment: Well basically it makes it like the object's not there, rather than merely like it can't be seen.

Comment: Specific examples: its Update() function won't be being called, it won't be found by Find() calls, it won't receive messages sent using SendMessage. Essentially it is inactive (hence the name) and activity is different to visibility.